# How to register Autofac component per http request in web.config?

Tags: web-config, autofac

In MVC3 application I have my custom implementation of IPrincipal.

I want to register it in web.config and then inject it to constructors by Autofac.

Autofac XML-configuration has attribute "instance-scope" but it does not support "per-http-request".

Any ideas how can I register component per http scope in web.config?

I already tried different combinations of per-dependency, single-instance or per-lifetime-scope  with ownership external but results are very buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nicholas Blumhardt from Autofac team told me **per-lifetime-scope** should be used.

When running under ASP.NET it is equivalent to per-HTTP-request in practical terms.

Comment: took me a long time to find this response. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from the source, registering per http request in XML configuration is not supported. As you mention, only the three `instance-scope` values (per-dependency, single-instance and per-lifetime-scope) are allowed.

Also, looking at how `per-http-request` scoping works, it uses the `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope` registration call with a `httpRequest` key. Again, there is no XML config way of configuring a "matching-lifetime-scope".

The way to go is configuration through code.