# How to register HttpContextBase with Autofac in Asp.Net (not MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

This is a Asp.net application (not MVC) running .Net 3.5

I did this:

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 ...

       builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
          .As<HttpContextBase>()
          .InstancePerHttpRequest();
 }
```

But it doesn't work.

The error I am getting this:

**No scope with a Tag matching 'httpRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being reqested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.**

So then I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7821781/305469

And I did this instead:

```
       builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
          .As<HttpContextBase>()
          .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But now when I do this:

```
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase context;

    public HttpService(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void ResponseRedirect(string url)
    {
        //Throws null ref exception
        context.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

and I got a Null Reference Exception.

Strangely, context.Response is not null, it is when I call .Redirect() that it throw.

I am wondering if using .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); is the problem.

BTW, I tried using Response.Redirect() and it works perfectly.

So what could be the problem?

Thanks,

Chi

Comment: In your first example with `InstancePerHttpRequest` what does it mean: doesn't work? Exception etc? And how do you resolve your `HttpService ` or how is it registered? When you mentioned the null ref exception what is the full stacktrace?

Comment: As nemesv said, why doesn't the .InstancePerHttpRequest() version work?

Comment: Thanks guys, I have updated the question to include the error I was getting for when I use .InstancePerHttpRequest()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though your `HttpService` class may be registered as a `SingleInstance()` (singleton) component. Or, one of the classes that has `IHttpService` as a dependency is a singleton.

When this occurs, even though you've set up Autofac to return a new `HttpContextBase` instance per HTTP request (or lifetime scope, which is also correct) the `HttpService` class will hang on to whichever `HttpContextBase` was current when the single `HttpService` instance was created.

To test this theory, try taking a dependency on `HttpContextBase` directly from a page, and see whether the problem still occurs. Figuring out which is the singleton component should be fairly straightforward if so.

Comment: This is exactly what I did! The HttpService and other services that calls HttpService are registered as Singletons. Thanks for your help Nicholas.

Comment: @ChiChan based on answer and your comment above, what did you change to make it work? did you change the lifetime/scope of the HttpService to something other than Singleton?

Comment: @Stokedout, yes, it was a while back, but I ended up turning the singleon registration of HttpService into another scope.

Answer (score 0):

Registering HttpContextWrapper with lifetime scope is like using RegisterInstance(), that is, you will always use the same instance of HttContextWrapper. The second request will therefore use the first request's HttpContext, resulting in some strange error.

Possible work-around: create your own wrapper for HttpContext and register it with instance life-time and let it use the current HttpContext internally:

```
public interface IMyWrapper
{
    void ResponseRedirect(string url);
}

public class MyWrapper : IMyWrapper
{
    public void ResponseRedirect(string url)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}

builder.Register(c => new MyWrapper())
    .As<IWrapper>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This way you don't inject the HttpContext, though. Not sure if that is important...

Comment: Thanks! This solution would work and is what I have currently, but I am still wondering if there is a way to peacefully register the context within Autofac.